# Webpack dev img folder always pointing to ./dist

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I am new to Webpack and Javascript frontend in General, so mostly I just use other's people boilerplate.

Below is my loader for png file I'm trying to load, it has 2 webpack config, this one is webpack.renderer.config.js:

```
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
    use: {
      loader: 'url-loader',
      query: {
        limit: 10000,
        name: 'imgs/[name].[ext]'
      }
    }
  },
```

and this one webpack.main.config.js (only notable code snippet):

```
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'app/dist')
  },
```

I'm utilizing Vue and Electron, by the way with boilerplate from [GREG](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue)

I can show `.png` image on `mainComponents.vue` if I put it on `./dist` folder directly, but always fail when I put in assets path as it should,

```
GET http://localhost:9080/assets/img/GeneralOutageFlow.png 404 (Not Found)
```

already tried using require and import but no success, here's my folder structure :

```
dist
src
|
|-main
|-renderer
  |
  |-assets
  |-components
     |-mainComponents
        |
        |-mainComponents.vue
```

How can I reference `GeneralOutageFlow.png` to `/assets/img` ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set [output.publicPath](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-publicpath) config to `/assets/`.

Like:

```
output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'app/dist'),
    publicPath: '/assets/'
},
```

Comment: It took me a while to tweak and figure out, but thank you!

Comment: the answer is     `publicPath: path.join(__dirname, 'app/src/assets')` by the way..